# Changing function scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I am trying to test this module:

```
function fa(){
    return "function A"
}
function fb(){
    return "function B + " + fa()
}
module.exports = {fa, fb}
```

I test it this way:

```
var myModule = require("./myModule")
var sinon = require("sinon")
var util = require('util');

sinon.stub(myModule,"fa").returns("stub")
console.log(myModule.fb()) //expect to display "function B + stub"
```

It is actually displaying "function B + function A"

If i replace the method body of fb by `return "function B + " + this.fa()` (notice the addition of `this.`) then it works as expected.

Is there a way to mock a function which haven't been called with `this`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no handy way to do that. You can create an object and use it as a reference, so you call that function as a "method"

What happens is that you are calling that function "as function", the function itself is different from the one that you are exporting.

This read can clarify more about what I said.
[Understanding 'this' keyword](https://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/)

Comment: Hum I am sorry but not only it doesn't answer my question, I believe it is also incorrect. The function I am exporting is exactly the same as its origin. The problem resides in how fa is resolved, either through a this reference or through the local scope. I know how to deal with `this` but I have no idea how to change a function scope. Binding a new context, either through a `bind` or using the `with` keyword wouldn't work.

Comment: You are right it's the same function. but when you do the mock for myModule.fa "fa" function belongs to myModule object. and when you call myModule.fb(), the "fa" function doesn't belong to the myModule object because you are calling it as a function

Comment: For don't face those reference issues, and don't use the 'this' keyword, I usually write my code like:
var exportObject = {};
exportObject.fa = function fa() {
  return 'function A';
};

exportObject.fb = function fb() {
  return 'function B + ' + exportObject.fa();
};
module.exports = exportObject;